# .matches("text/.*") throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a FilenameFilter that filters everything but directories and files with the mime type text and all subtypes (or supposed to any way...) however when I use the .matches() function it throws a NullPointerException. When I looked into it, the .matches() function throws a NullPointerException when the regex syntax is incorrect.

```
FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter()
{
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
    {
        File tmp = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + name);
        if (tmp.isDirectory())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            String type = null;
            String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + name);
            if (extension != null)
            {
                MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
            }
            return type.matches("text/.*");
        }
    }
};
```

There was a file being passed that did not have a mime therefore it output null. Here is the fix:

```
FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter()
{
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
    {
        File tmp = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + name);
        if (tmp.isDirectory())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            String type = "";
            String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + name);
            if (extension != null)
            {
                MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                if (type != null)
                {
                    return type.matches("text/.*");
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Here is the description from eclipse:
 String android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(String extension)

public String getMimeTypeFromExtension (String extension) 
Since: API Level 1 
Return the MIME type for the given extension.

Parameters
extension  A file extension without the leading '.'

Returns
The MIME type for the given extension or null iff there is none.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that _type_ is null.  It's very easy to determine by add a debug statement: _System.out.println("type: " + type);_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your String variable `type` might be `null` if it doesn't enter into this if statement:

```
  if (extension != null)
  {
     MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
     type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension)
  }
```

So it's highly possible that you get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: it would return false, wouldn't it? It would be like saying:

Comment: If you haven't specifically tested whether or not the variable named  _type_ is null, please do.  99.999% of questions like this are just null Strings.... Your if statement checks _extension_ then you call _matches_ on a different variable (named _type_).  The variable named _type_ is almost certainly null.

Comment: String a = ""; return a.matches("uh");

Comment: @TimberwolfProgrammers you are trying to call a method on a null object. It throws exception. How can it return false then? You think wrong about the flow of the program. If you get an exception you cannot return a value from a method unless there is a return statement in finally clause.

Comment: There's almost no doubt that _type_ is null.

Comment: public boolean matches (String regularExpression) 
Since: API Level 1 
Tests whether this string matches the given regularExpression. This method returns true only if the regular expression matches the entire input string. A common mistake is to assume that this method behaves like contains(CharSequence); if you want to match anywhere within the input string, you need to add .* to the beginning and end of your regular expression. See matches(String, CharSequence). 
Throws
 if the syntax of the supplied regular expression is not valid. 
NullPointerException  if regularExpression == null

Comment: also it is only called if a file is passed through the FilenameFilter

Comment: Throws if the syntax of the supplied regular expression is not valid.

Comment: @TimberwolfProgrammers there is no problem with your regex in your code. we are talking about null references in Java. do you know what happens if you invoke a method on a null reference? search for it then you will be done, ok?

Comment: You literally declare the variable named _type_ to be null.  Then you proceed to invoke a method on your null variable.  This is the very definition of a _NullPointerException_ in its most simple form.  We are trying to do you a favor by telling you _exactly_ what is wrong with your code.  It _can't_ be anything other than what we're saying.

Comment: public String getMimeTypeFromExtension (String extension) 
Since: API Level 1 
Return the MIME type for the given extension.

Parameters
extension  A file extension without the leading '.' 

Returns
The MIME type for the given extension or null iff there is none.

Comment: @TimberwolfProgrammers -   So... In other words: the variable named _type_ is null.

Answer (score 0):

The variable named *type* is null.

Add a line of code and you can see this for yourself:

```
System.out.println("type: " + type);
```

The output will be null.

You have a problem elsewhere in your code that has nothing to do with your regex.

Comment: @TimberwolfProgrammers -  I'm sure there's a console somewhere... And you can certainly debug your app with Eclipse.  I haven't done much work with Eclipse or Android, but I"m pretty sure that's the whole purpose of LogCat.  I think the main issue you're experiencing is that you need to learn how to debug your code.